# confusion for selecting inapp purchase item in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have to create two inapp purchase item one with $3 and one with $5. If any user selects $3 then he can buy any 5 items from the app and i also want to allow user to buy this $3 item again to purchase another 5 items from the app.My app have hundreds of items.I want one time purchase only.So i have to go with Non-consumable in app purchase item.

But my question is how user can bye $3 item to purchase another 5 items from my app. I am confuse to manage this kind of in app purchase. Can any one please guide me for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use consumable purchase — this will let your user buy that $3 item as many times as he wants.

Comment: @Viral: Nikita is right. The way you described your problem the only way would be to go with consumables. The problem is that you don't have 1:1 between purchases and consumables - if user 'temporarily' deletes your app and doesn't back up it's data before you'll have no way of knowing what items he selected for hes purchases. So you might even want to consider a simple server on your side to keep track of user's purchases and item selections.

Comment: He can restorePurchases, can't he?

Comment: He can restore purchases, that's true. But that will only tell him how many item-packs his user bought. What i mean is: if user can select **any** 5 items out of lets say 100 for each purchase he will also need a way to restore this user's selection (in case his database or userdefaults get corrupted).

Comment: But he can let his user select the items next time,by the amount he already bought.But maybe that wouldn't suit his type of products thought

Comment: That's also true. :) Let's see what Viral says on this.

Comment: thanks Nikita and rokjarc. i like your idea and continue with that.